# how to pass a view element to another view as command parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, command

i have a window with this in the xaml:

```
<view:ToolBar DataContext="{Binding}"/>

<Grid>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
           <GridView>
               <GridViewColumn>
               ....//all the columns
           </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And the toolbar is a class which inherits from usercontrol. In the toolbar.xaml, I have a button, which has a command.

```
<ToggleButton Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonStyle}" 
              IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"
              Command="{x:Static ui:GridHelper.UpdateColumns}">
</ToggleButton>
```

Everytime that button is clicked, i want to pass in the column headers of the list view to the command. but i cant work out how to connect the toolbar and listview since theyre totally separate. any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should use a view model which holds this kind of information like column headers and column data. Other controls can easily bind to this data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need a new DependencyProperty in your ToolBar control. You can read about DependencyProperties here :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview

This DependencyProperty, in your case, will be a property that will be a list of columns. And since it is a DependencyProperty, you will be able to bind a value to it in Xaml, and from your ToolBar control, retrieve these columns.

Now, as to how to bind the list of columns to your DependencyProperty, you have a couple of options. The first one would be to bind it directly to your ListView. It woule look like this:

```
<view:ToolBar YourDependencyProperty={Binding TheListOfColumns, ElementName=MyGridView}"/>

<Grid>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
           <GridView x:Name="MyGridView">
               <GridViewColumn>
               ....//all the columns
           </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The other option is like BionicCode described in his comment to your question, by keeping the columns in the ViewModel and binding to the ViewModel property. But for that, you will have to create the columns in the ViewModel, and not in the Xaml. The binding would look like this :

```
<view:ToolBar YourDependencyProperty={Binding ListOfColumnsPropertyFromTheViewModel}"/>
```

Hope that helps!